# Break Line each X characters if it's a space, if not wait for a space

Tags: javascript, string

I have this working script that is breaking the line each 79 characters. I would like to add a condition that it does only break the line if the 79th character is a space, if not, then it will break at the next space inputed. (So that the words will not be broke)

Here is the function I have currently. (I don't know how to add this condition in the expression)

```
function myFunction() {
    var long_string = document.getElementById('textg').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('textg').innerHTML = long_string.replace(/(.{79})/g, "$1<br>");
}
```

Comment: JS can't have variables named with `-` in name.

Comment: @Justinas: I'm assuming that first example is pseudo-code

Comment: "Wait for one"?

Comment: @Justinas as Cerbrus said, this was simply a way to show you what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```js
var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquet feugiat enim. Nam viverra sapien quis nisi consequat, nec viverra ligula tempus. Pellentesque sed diam id velit malesuada pellentesque. Vivamus nec condimentum purus. Suspendisse purus lacus, elementum non feugiat molestie, volutpat nec nisl. Vivamus mauris eros, pulvinar eu velit vitae, hendrerit venenatis velit. In accumsan nec lacus eget aliquet. Integer ullamcorper accumsan lacinia. Sed eleifend dignissim libero. Aenean sodales imperdiet ipsum, ut vulputate ante accumsan sit amet. Nunc mollis tristique finibus. Donec pellentesque orci nec ante efficitur scelerisque. Cras ullamcorper euismod sem in pretium. Morbi felis turpis, venenatis sit amet erat mattis, consectetur commodo nisi. Aliquam varius ultrices orci eget tristique.";

var broken = str.replace(/(.{79}[^ ]* )/g, "$1<br />");

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = broken;
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

The magic is in [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/mpq7Xs/2):

`/(.{79}[^ ]* )/g`

It [captures](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

- 79 characters: `.{79}` +
- Anything that follows it that isn't a space: `[^ ]*` +
- The trailing space .

The replace then replaces the captured section with "that" + a linebreak (`"$1<br />"`)

---

Note that this will result in spaces before the `<br />`, in the string:
`enim. <br />Nam`

If you want to get rid of those, move that last space out of the capture group, in the regex. The space will then be discarded:

`/(.{79}[^ ]*) /g`

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for ! And thank you for the good explainations ! It does help to understand these regex.. I'm kinda new with these. Do you use to have a codex about them maybe ?

Comment: You're very welcome! These are some good sites: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ and https://regex101.com/

Comment: @Ezhno: I updated the answer a bit. The `+` in the regex meant it didn't break if the 79th character is a pace. That's fixed now.

Comment: I noticed another problem, if the 79th character isn't a space, it doesn't break the line

Comment: @Ezhno: _"Isn't a space"_ means it's something else that's not alphanumeric? If you want it to be able to break at something other than spaces, the spaces in here: `[^ ]* ` should be replaced with the characters which allow for linebreaks. For example: `[^ ,.]*[ ,.]`

Comment: I see. Un must add an asterix for each character ? Or what is the separator ? 
Is it correct if I do something like [ ],[a],[b]...

Comment: @Ezhno: No, add the characters within the `[]`. For your example: `[^ ab]*[ ab]` That second pait of `[]` in't there in the answer, because we only needed to check for the single space (` `). When that position can one of multiple characters, you need a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that says _"This position needs to be one of the following characters"_

Answer (score -1):

Simply check if it's more than 79 chars and not white space, than set flag.

```
var force = false; // in global scope

if ((longString == 79 && lastCharacter == ' ') || (lastCharacter == ' ' && force)) {
    breakline();
    force = false;
} else if (longString > 79 && lastCharacter != ' ') {
    force = true;
}
```

Comment: `breakline()`? What's that?